# Read in Numbers from a File in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file called `points.dat` which reads something like:
5
2 5
-1 18
0 6
1 -1
10 0

The first number is how many ordered pairs there are.  The next 5 lines contain those ordered pairs.  What can I do to read in the first number, determine how many points there are (from here I can `malloc` an array of `structs` to store the points in).

My problem is that `fgetc` doesn't really do the job here.  What if the first number is two digits?  Say the first number is 10.  `fgetc` will only retrieve the '1'.  Also, `fgets` doesn't really work, since you need to supply it the length of the amount of characters you want to read in.  The same applies for `fscanf`.

The real trouble comes in when it's time to retrieve the ordered pairs.  I have no idea how to do this either.  My only thoughts so far is look at a line: if it sees non-spaces or non-'\n's, it will read in the number as the x coordinate of point 1.  Loop.  Get y coordinate.  Once it hits a '\n', it will now move on to the next line, and begin looking for values to store in the next `struct` in the array of `structs`.

(While doing this, I also need to be sure `atoi` can convert all of these into integers... ).

If anyone has any ideas to help, they are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first line use `int numValuesRead = fscanf(file, "%d", &totnums);`

Then, use `numValuesRead = fscanf(file, "%d %d", &num1, &num2);` to read the other lines.

`fscanf` returns the number of value read. You should always check it.

Comment: Thanks @shahbaz... The shift didn't work on that 2 :-) The `;` was a little pedantic (using the `;` you make the OP think mine is a complete line. Technically he should check the return value of `fscanf`)

Comment: honestly, I just wanted the change to fill the minimum character requirement! :D That's why I also added the "Then, "

Comment: @Shahbaz :-) :-) Aaaah... I though someone wanted to correct my bad English :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        int x, y;
} Point;

int main ()
{
        int numOf;
        Point *myPoints = NULL;
        FILE *myfile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
        if (myfile == NULL)
            perror ("Error opening file"); //or return 1;
        else
        {
            fscanf(myfile, "%d", &numOf);
            myPoints = (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point) * numOf);
            while ( !feof (myfile) && numOf-- )
            {
                fscanf(myfile, "%d %d", &(myPoints[numOf].x), &(myPoints[numOf].y));
            }
        }
        fclose(myfile);
        //Do stuff with array
        free ((void *)myPoints);
        getchar();//Press enter to close debugger etc.
        return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the delay.